# getting Invalid argument value while selecting last generated ID

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to select the last generaed ID but I'm getting **Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException** Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: model.Category

here is the insertion code

```
public static void add_product(Product product) {
        Connection cnx;
        long key = -1L;

            cnx = Connect.getConnection();
            String req = "insert into product(name, category) values(?,?)";

            PreparedStatement st = cnx.prepareStatement(req, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            st.setString(1, product.getName());
            st.setObject(2, product.getCategory());

            st.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = st.getGeneratedKeys();

        if (rs.next()) {
            key = rs.getLong(1);

        }
}
```

and here is the servlet code

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
int id_category = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("category"));
Category category = DAO.get_category(id_category );


    Product p = new Product (name, category);

    DAO.add_product(p);
```

***Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: model.Category***

***at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setSerializableObject(PreparedStatement.java:44***

Comment: You save `category` as **Object** and then retrieve it as **String**.  So what type is it?

Comment: category is of type Category but this is not the problem because whenever I display it's value in the console using System.out.println >> it is shown. it is an sql error

Comment: System.out.println uses toString() method to display the object content. did you try with get product api? is it mapping your db data with Product?

Comment: what's product api ? @prasadg

Comment: When asking about an exception, always post the exact and complete stack trace of the exception. The exception you get probably has nothing to do with the code you posted.

Comment: Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: model.Category @JBNizet

Comment: I mean get  product by id

Comment: So Product.Category is not a String, but an object of type Category. You can't store an object in a database column (except in its serialized form, hence the exception, but you really don't want to do that). Store the **ID** of the category.

Comment: yes I've already solve this problem by adding "implements Serializable" but now I'm getting a new error @JBNizet
"Data truncated for column 'category' at row 1"

Comment: Again, don't do that. Don't store serialized Java objects in database columns. Store the **ID** of the category in the table.

Comment: @JBNizet yeah this is what I'm doing, it is surely something else

Comment: It's not what you're doing since you're calling setObject() with an object of type Category as argument. So you're serializing the whole Category object to store it in a column. Don't do that. Get the **ID** of the category, and save that in the column, as a foreign key to the category table.

Comment: @JBNizet have u seen that ? int id_category = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("category"));
Category category = DAO.get_category(id_category );

Comment: Yes, but that's not inserting anything to the product table. What is inserting something in the product table is `st.executeUpdate();`, after having done `st.setObject(2, product.getCategory());`, which is setting the second parameter of the insert quesry to `product.getCategory()` which is not the ID of the category, but the whole Category object.

Comment: if I change setObject() to setInt it gives The method setInt(int, int) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, Category ) what shall I do @JBNizet

Comment: You will insert the **ID** of the category instead of trying to insert the Category object itself.  `setInt(2, product.getCategory().getId())`.

Comment: no changes @JBNizet

Comment: How could there be no change? There is a change. Maybe you still have an error, but the error can't possibly e the same. Errors are meaningful. You need to read them.

Comment: @JBNizet unfortunately is the same

Comment: @JBNizet it's working now ;)